# CentOS why the Google Apps Engine do not work? Even applying the last patch mentioned in there fix

Tags: python, google-app-engine, centos, rhel, centos6

Google Apps Engine was working in my CentOS there was no changes made, but suddently stop working since yesterday. then i followed the patch for Google Apps Engine but still its not starting up. how do resolve it?

```
[root@ip-10-59-143-73 tmp]# uname -a
Linux ip-10-59-143-73 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 9 08:03:13 EST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

According to Patch:

http://code.google.com/p/nose-gae/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=61

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=8459

Line 56/57 is changed, like the patch but still problem:

```
 55   py_file = __file__.replace('.pyc', '.py')
 56   #dir_paths = [os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(py_file))),
 57   #             os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(py_file))]
 58   uncompiled_file = __file__.rstrip("c") if __file__.endswith("pyc") else __file__
 59   dir_paths = [os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(uncompiled_file))),
 60                os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(uncompiled_file))]
 61   for dir_path in dir_paths:
 62     sibling_path = os.path.join(dir_path, sibling)
 63     if os.path.exists(sibling_path):
```

Patch is not helping:

```
[root@ip-10-59-143-73 tmp]# Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/tmp/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 76, in <module>
    _DIR_PATH = _get_dir_path(os.path.join('lib', 'ipaddr'))
  File "/var/tmp/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 66, in _get_dir_path
    'file and %s.' % sibling)
ValueError: Could not determine directory that contains both, this file and lib/ipaddr.
```

***EDIT:*** issues

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=9176

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 6.x: working with latest version:

https://googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/google_appengine_1.8.1.zip